# Conversion of GRIB and NetCDF to my database

Tags: convert, netcdf, grib

.

[image]

I have downloaded "High Resolution Initial Conditions" climate forecast data for one day, it was in extension .tar.gz so I extracted it in my local directory and I get the files like in the attached image.

I think, that the files without extension are GRIB data (because first word in them is "GRIB"). So i want to get data from the big files (GRIB and NetCDF formats containing climate data like temerature & pressure in grid) to my database, but they are binary. 
Can you recommend me some easy way for getting data from these files? I can't get any information about handling their datasets on their website.

Converting these files to .csv would be nice, but I can't find any working program to convert the GRIB files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) to convert your data to csv.

> wgrib2: -csv (comma separated values)
>
> The -csv option writes the grid values to a specified file as a comma
>   separated values (text) which can be imported into a spread sheet.
>   This function is similar to -text with a different output.
>
> "time0","time1","field","level",longitude,latitude,grid-value
>
> Time0 is the reference time, that is usually the analysis or start of
>   the forecast time. Time1 is the verification time. For analyses, Time0
>   and Time1 will be the same.

```
wgrib2 fcst.grb2 -csv junk 

$ cat junk 
"2007-03-26 00:00:00","2007-03-26 00:00:00","HGT","1000 mb",0,-90,164.1
"2007-03-26 00:00:00","2007-03-26 00:00:00","HGT","1000 mb",0.5,-90,164.1
"2007-03-26 00:00:00","2007-03-26 00:00:00","HGT","1000 mb",1,-90,164.1
"2007-03-26 00:00:00","2007-03-26 00:00:00","HGT","1000 mb",1.5,-90,164.1
```

beside this there is a python library which name is [pygrib](http://code.google.com/p/pygrib/) (python module for reading GRIB files). i think you can read your grib files and then convert them to csv file or anything with it.

> Python module for reading and writing GRIB (editions 1 and 2) files.
>   GRIB is the World Meterological Organization standard for distributing
>   gridded data. The module is a python interface to the GRIB API C
>   library from the European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
>   (ECMWF).

Some Example code:

```
import pygrib

grbs = pygrib.open('sampledata/flux.grb')  
grb = grbs.select(name='Maximum temperature')[0]

#

maxt = grb.values # same as grb['values']
maxt.shape, maxt.min(), maxt.max()
#(94, 192) 223.7 319.9
```

get the latitudes and longitudes of the grid:

```
lats, lons = grb.latlons()
lats.shape, lats.min(), lats.max(), lons.shape, lons.min(), lons.max()
(94, 192) -88.5419501373 88.5419501373  0.0 358.125
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thank You very much, the wgrib2 looks that it works nice, but it told me "grib1 message ignored (use wgrib)", so I downloaded wgrib (1), but it doesn't have the feature for exporting to other formats (like .csv), so what is the best way to convert grib(1) to .csv or to grib2? I can find it, but I think it helps this topic to be fully answered to others with same problem...

Comment: Sometimes you want to use a feature of wgrib2 on a grib-1 file. Since wgrib2 doesn't do grib-1, you are out of luck unless you convert the file into grib-2. Some files can be converted into grib2 by the [cnvgrib](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/codes/GRIB2/) utility.

Comment: True, I have read that and downloaded cvngrib, it needed f95 (fortran) to install, so I installed it, but it was for some old version of GCC, so I gave up...

Answer (score 1):

I created a [tiny makefile](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/9610352) that might help you

1. install `wgrib2` ;
2. get data (you need to add code for your specific data-source) ;
3. convert to csv using @Aragon suggestion ;
4. extract only data using `awk` (update to your need).

### Usage

First, **update the `gribFile`, `csvFile`, `csvFilteredFile`** variables to your need.

```
make extract-data
```

Running the `extract-data` will run need task to be complete its action. Namely:

```
# make convert2csv
# make get-data
# make install
```